# Regular expression to search into a subset

Tags: regex, search

I'm looking for a way to search a string into a big set, but without considering strings that contain a certain sequence of chars.
For example:

The original set is:

```
proc-smile
func-get-aaa
func-get-smile
func-has-ccc
func-has-ddd
func-hello-bye
func-cheers-hey
func-smile-lol
```

If the user search for "sm", the regex must consider only the subset composed by strings that don't contain "-get-" or "-has-" substrings. Hence, result must be:

```
proc-smile
func-smile-lol
```

(without func-get-smile)

Thanks for the help

Comment: What is the type of the regex? perl, bash, etc.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
^(?!.*-(?:get|has)-).*sm
```

will match strings that contain `sm` but don't have either `-get-` or `-has-` in them.

`(?!...)` is a negative [lookahead assertion](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html).